# Make snapshot of page state in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, next.js

I faced with some problem while developing Next.js application. It is rather an architectural issue.

I want to switch between routes, but keeping all the states on the page so that I can return to page without loosing it's state. I understand that I need to use initalProps at the top level. But this is only suitable for simple cases. Let's take an example where there're hundreds of states on a page with different levels of hierarchy. Is it possible to make a snapshot of all page states?

I look towards [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) from React. Also, I think Redux would help me, but I don't use it in the application at all and it's one more dependency. Perhaps this can be solved using the [Context Api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you have global state that you need to share between different pages and the state is **simple** you can use `Context API`, the `Component` needs to be wrapped by the `ContextProvider` in the custom app component in `_app.js`.

The pseudo-code might look something like this for your use case,

```js
// context and the provider component

export const MyContext = React.createContext();


export const MyCtxProvider = ({ children }) => {
   
  // state logic  
  
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={/* state value */}>
       {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

in `_app.js`

```js
import App from 'next/app'
import { MyCtxProvider } from './path-to-myctxprovider'

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return (
      <MyCtxProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MyCtxProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-context-api) from nextjs repo that uses context API to share state between pages.

But if your global state is somewhat **complex** i.e. you want to keep both server state(fetched data from a remote API) and UI state in the global state, you might wanna use a state management system like `redux` in this case. There are a lot of [examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples) in the nextjs repo showing how to implement it. You can start from there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, it will be an architectual problem. For global state management you need to use e.g: Redux, graphql, `ContextAPI`, or give a global state to your app in `pages/_app.js`. That will wrap your pages, and provide a cross pages state.(You can modify, and reuse that)

 **Opnion**: Implement `Redux`, if it"s really need. (for large amount of data in the state). Because it"s easier to implement, then remove it.
 **Other case:** Use the inbuild `ContextAPI`, or the `pages/_app.js` state handler till it"s fit for your application.

Comment: Can the context  api do a snapshot of states? Or I need to save all states in it?

Comment: You can do a snapshot, whenever the page `unmuount` the page.
like:

`useEffect(() => {
  console.log("MOUNTING THE PAGE");
  return ()=> {
    console.log("UNMOUNT_THE_PAGE_CALL_THE_SNAPSHOT_API_HERE");
  }
}, [])`

Comment: But for sure its better if your application working with `context api`modify the data direct in that `context`, and reuse it when the user navigates back to the page, and nothing to do with the `snapshots`